# ms sql query help. subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my query:

```
SELECT        
      Bills.BillDate,  
      Client.ClientName, 
         (SELECT bills.NetAmount 
          FROM Bills 
          Where Bills.BillDate Between  DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()) as '30 days'
FROM  Client INNER JOIN
      Vessel ON Client.ClientID = Vessel.ClientID INNER JOIN
      Bills ON Vessel.VesselID = Bills.VesselID
      GROUP BY Bills.BillDate,  Client.ClientName
```

Comment: Your 3rd column `30 days` returned more than 1 result.

Comment: Warning: using GETDATE() like that will prevent you to use any index. I suggest to calculate date in a variable before the select and use it.

Comment: i want to select all the [netamount] of the [clientname] where the [BillDate] falls in the period of today minus 30 days. thanks

Comment: Why do you do GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are involved? If you just want to remove duplicate rows, use SELECT DISTINCT instead. Do you perhaps want the SUM of bills.NetAmount for the last 30 days?

Comment: sorry about that I tried the sum(case when) functions earlier and forgot to remove the group by when i tried the subquery. The [clientname] has multiple [netamount] records within the date period that is why the subquery returned more than 1 row. I want to select the [billdate], [clientname] and all the [netamount] within the 30 day period. can it be done in a query? thanks

Comment: Using getdate like that does not preclude the use of an index.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT 
    Bills.BillDate, 
    Client.ClientName, 
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 bills.NetAmount 
        FROM Bills 
        WHERE 
            Bills.BillDate BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
    ) AS '30 days' 
FROM Client 
INNER JOIN Vessel 
    ON Client.ClientID = Vessel.ClientID 
INNER JOIN Bills 
    ON Vessel.VesselID = Bills.VesselID 
GROUP BY 
    Bills.BillDate, Client.ClientName
```

**TOP 1** will get only **1** result from the inner query.

Answer (score 0):

Adjusted to SUM the bills.NetAmount for the last 30 days:

```
SELECT        
      Bills.BillDate,  
      Client.ClientName, 
      SUM(bills.NetAmount) as '30 days'
FROM  Client INNER JOIN
      Vessel ON Client.ClientID = Vessel.ClientID INNER JOIN
      Bills ON Vessel.VesselID = Bills.VesselID
WHERE Bills.BillDate BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY Bills.BillDate,  Client.ClientName
```